# Capturing variables from surrounding abstractions in sicp macros

Tags: macros, scheme, sicp

I am trying to write a higher level function in sicp which takes variable number of *single argument functions* and returns another function which is a composition of all passed functions. Let's say the higher level function is named `compose` then doing `(compose f g)` should return me the function `fog` or `f(g(x))` where f and g are some *single argument functions*.
I'm using define-syntax construct of sicp to achieve this and so far I have the following code:

```lisp
(define-syntax apply-to-all-functions
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((apply-to-all-functions f) (f x))
    ((apply-to-all-functions f g) (f (apply-to-all-functions g)))
    ((apply-to-all-functions f . g) (f (apply-to-all-functions . g)))
    ))

(define-syntax compose
  (syntax-rules (x)
    ((compose) (lambda (x) x))
    ((compose g) (lambda (x) (apply-to-all-functions g)))
    ((compose . g) (lambda (x) (apply-to-all-functions . g)))
    ))
```

In this code, I am trying to capture `x` which is bound in the `lambda` in function/macro `compose`, however when I create a composite function and call it on some value, I get the error that identifier `x` is unbound.
Can someone please explain how can I capture a variable in the above kind of setup or some other way to solve this problem.

Thanks!:)

Comment: Is there some reason you are not writing `compose` as a function, which it normally would be?

Comment: I want `compose` to take variable number of arguments as stated in the question e.g. I should also be able to create some function `f(g(h(x)))` if I want to(A composition of any `n` number of functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### *... or some other way to solve this problem.*

I don't understand why OP code is attempting to use macros to create a higher-order procedure here. A `compose` procedure that takes one or more procedure arguments can be easily written using the dot syntax for procedure definitions.

```
(define (compose f . fs)
  (if (null? fs)
      (lambda (x) (f x))
      (let ((g (apply compose fs)))
        (lambda (x) (f (g x))))))
```

Here, when only one argument is provided, a procedure that applies `f` to a single argument `x` is returned. Otherwise, a procedure that applies `f` to the composition of the remaining procedure arguments, with the final procedure argument applied to a single argument `x`, is returned.

Here is a REPL demonstration:

```
> (define (double x) (* 2 x))
> (define (reciprocal x) (/ 1 x))
> (define (square x) (* x x))
> (define (add1 x) (+ x 1))

> (define doros (compose double reciprocal square))
> (define rodos (compose reciprocal double square))
> (doros 4)
1/8
> (rodos 4)
1/32

> (define dosoaor (compose double square add1 reciprocal))
> (define soroaod (compose square reciprocal add1 double))

> (= (dosoaor 4)
     (double (square (add1 (reciprocal 4)))))
#t
> (dosoaor 4)
25/8
> (= (soroaod 4)
     (square (reciprocal (add1 (double 4)))))
#t
> (soroaod 4)
1/81
```

The composed procedure `doros` should first square its argument, then take the reciprocal of the result, and finally return twice that result. So, `(doros 4)` should evaluate to `(* 2 (/ 1 (* 4 4)))`  ==>  `1/8`, as seen in the above REPL demonstration.

Similarly, `rodos` should first square its argument, then double the result, and finally take the reciprocal of that result. Thus `(rodos 4)` should evaluate to `(/ 1 (* 2 (* 4 4)))`  ==>  `1/32`, matching the REPL result.

The tests composing four procedures are successful, as well.

Comment: Although I am curious, why does scheme doesn't capture the bindings from it's enclosing environment in my example? If we were to do the same thing in an imperative language(like C), macros there will capture the bindings from the enclosing procedure(literal text substitution happens there).

Comment: @ArpitBhadauria -- free variables in a `syntax-rules` form refer to bindings in the environment in which the macro is _defined_, not the environment in which it is _used_. For a macro at the top level, this means that the free `x` in the definition of `apply-to-all-functions` refers to a non-existent binding at the top level; `apply-to-all-functions` does _not_ know about the environment inside the `compose` macro.